# What anime is this talisman with a cross and three 6s from?

Tags: merchandise

All I have is this talisman thing:

[image: talisman]

Can anyone tell me what anime this is from?

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's from an Anime as something like that [isn't unique to anime](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=symbol+necklaces&tbm=isch&imgil=W_M8yEOSpxWCvM%253A%253B8GfhIRiHQY5JTM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.sunnybeachjewelry.com%25252FLeather-Necklace-Silver-Earth-Tree-of-Life-Symbol%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=W_M8yEOSpxWCvM%253A%252C8GfhIRiHQY5JTM%252C_&usg=__U0T1p29wIRvvxabRZDdmnBUcxXo%3D)

Comment: only the insistence of the owner that it was identified on its original packaging as being associated with a particular anime. we no longer have the packaging and she doesn't remember.

Comment: If it's a licensed product there's almost certainly going to be a copyright notice of some sort on it. Check the back and the outside edges.

Comment: nada. it might be an unlicensed product like from etsy or something.

Comment: Seeing the cross and 3 6's i assume, if it were from an anime, the anime has some sort of religious connection and to that of [The Beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_beast_%28Revelation%29#Mark_of_the_beast)